# html css で<p>の色を赤にしたいが適用されない

Tags: html, css

提示画像はディレクトリ構造のスクショで提示コードはその中身です。

タイトル通りですが「cssで設定した `<p>` を赤色に設定することが出来ない」ですどうすればいいのでしょうか？
ディレクトリ構造を確認しまたがやはり正しい場所に居るためどうすればいいかわかりません。参考サイト通りにやりましたが適用されません。

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
<head>
    <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
p {
    color: red;
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Mozilla is cool</h1>
    <img src="images/firefox-icon.png" alt="The Firefox logo: a flaming fox surrounding the Earth.">

    <p>At Mozilla, we’re a global community of</p>

    <ul> <!-- changed to list in the tutorial -->
      <li>technologists</li>
      <li>thinkers</li>
      <li>builders</li>
    </ul>

    <p>working together to keep the Internet alive and accessible, so people worldwide can be informed contributors and creators of the Web. We believe this act of human collaboration across an open platform is essential to individual growth and our collective future.</p>

    <p>Read the <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/manifesto/">Mozilla Manifesto</a> to learn even more about the values and principles that guide the pursuit of our mission.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<head> </head>` の中に下記のコードが無いのが原因でした。

```html
<link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```